# Restrict searching result with matches of multiple fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to restrict the searching result with more than one searching words in different document fields.

For example, I have 3 fields `field1`, `field2` and `field3` and two searching words `word1` and `word2`. I'd like to have all the documents with any two of the fields matching these words separately, e.g.:

- `field1` matches `word1` and `field3` matches `word2`, or
- `field2` matches `word1` and `field3` matches `word2`, or
- `field1` matches `word2` and `field2` matches `word1`, or
- ... ...

How should I write the query?

Btw. I'm using ElasticSearch 5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "word1",
                        "fields": ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query": "word2",
                        "fields": ["field1", "field2", "field3"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it then possible to make it parsing the words and adding `multi_match` queries automatically. For example if I have given 3 instead of 2 searching words, there will be effectively another `multi_match` added?

Comment: Yes, you just need additional multi_match entries, but I don't think elastic can do this for you - you would need to construct the query beforehand in the client application.

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"term": {"field1 ": "word1"}},
                            {"term": {"field3 ": "word2"}}
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"term": {"field2 ": "word1"}},
                            {"term": {"field3 ": "word2"}}
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {"term": {"field1 ": "word2"}},
                            {"term": {"field2 ": "word1"}}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't answering my question. The query has to be matching ANY of the 2 fields. The 3 bullet points are just examples. Should I write all the combinations in the query?

Comment: No my bad, i am tired and missread the subject. The next answer is correct ;).